# DNAT on the POSTROUTING chain

Tags: iptables, firewall

What happens if I try to do a DNAT in the POSTROUTING chain of the NAT table in iptables?

Suppose I change the destination IP of the packet in the POSTROUTING chain to an address that should get routed via a different interface. What would happen to the packet?

1. Would the host be able to route the packet to the correct interface even after all the routing decisions have been made.
2. Or would the packet still be sent via the interface which was decided in the routing decisions before.

Comment: I think you already know the answer :)

Comment: @Dan Seems like the second one to me... the routing would probably be done by the next host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options are incorrect. The right answer is :

3. An error will occur.

Because DNAT can only be used in PREROUTING or OUTPUT chains.

Answer (score 0):

To see the packet flow through iptables check the NetFilter iptables packet flow diagram.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

In short, the routing decision occurs after PREROUTING and **before** POSTROUTING.

Besides, I think you cannot do DNAT on POSTROUTING anyway. iptables will throw a syntax error.